# Android Google Play APIs - This seller is not able to accept payments at this time

Tags: java, android

When I try to make payments from my app, I got the following error from Google purchases APIs

**The seller is not able to accept payments at this time [BM-CCH-18]**

What's happening?

Answer (score 1):

According to a response from Google [on this forum](http://www.androidpub.com/index.php?mid=devfree&document_srl=2672315):

> Hello,
>
> As you may know from your existing banking relationships, European law
>   requires that payments providers take steps to verify the identities
>   of their customers. Google has designed procedures to comply with
>   those requirements while protecting and respecting the confidentiality
>   of your personal information.
>
> Please be aware that your account has been temporarily suspended, and
>   will remain so, until you have completed our verification process. To
>   learn how to resolve this issue, please visit the following link
>   within three business days:
>
> https://support.google.com/checkout/sell/contact/verification_svida?hl=en-GB
>
> Please note that failure to provide the requested verification
>   documents may result in account closure.
>
> Sincerely, Your Google Checkout Team

In short, it appears that your Google Wallet merchant account is suspended until your identity is verified. Follow the link above to go through the verification process.